# How to break the loop on mouse click event

Tags: java, loops, swt, mouse, break

I have the snippet class. How to break the following loop by mouse click event?

```
public class Sample {

    private static Label label;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 70);
        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        button.setText("Go");
        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
                while (true) {
                    int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                    int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
                    label.setText(x + ":" + y);
                }
            }});
        label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: I want to click on the specified text box which is located on the external appliaction and then the loop shoud stpped. I want to remeber clicked text box location (x, y).

Comment: How do you know when a text box in an external application has been clicked?

Comment: I don't need to know when a text box has been clicked. I need to know if mouse button was clicked, wherever it has been done.

Comment: So you just want to know when your `button` has been clicked? That's what the `SWT.Selection` `Listener` already does, so why the `while (true)` loop?

Comment: No. I want to know when mouse button has been clicked.

Comment: Which mouse button? If it's just the left, then `SWT.Selection` will do that, otherwise use `SWT.MouseDown`.

Comment: For example left mouse button. But I think, SWT.Selection and SWT.MouseDown works when I click on the control with this selection. I need listener which will listen on whole screen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you want to do. Maybe someone else will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have what I wanted.
Thank you Baz for your help.

```
public class Sample {

private static Label label;

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 70);
    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Go");
    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            Shell screenShell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);
            screenShell.setMaximized(true);
            screenShell.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
            screenShell.setAlpha(120);
            screenShell.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
                @Override
                public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                    screenShell.close();                        
                }});
            screenShell.open();
            Display.getCurrent().timerExec(10, new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!screenShell.isDisposed()) {
                        int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                        int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
                        label.setText(x + ":" + y);
                        Display.getCurrent().timerExec(10, this);
                    }
                }});    
        }});

    label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
```